# Showing weak convergence with a trick

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I wonder if my reasoning works: Given $1 < p < \infty$ let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers and define $f_n(x) = a_n$ if $x \in [n,n+1]$ and $0$ otherwise. I claim that if $(a_n)$ is bounded then $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^p$.

My idea is that $$\int f_ng = \int_n^{n+1}a_ng \leq M\int_n^{n+1}g \leq M\|g\|_q, \ \ \forall g \in L^q(\mathbb{R}).$$Now since the right side is independent of $n$ we can take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and since $g$ is arbitrary, we can make the the right side as small as we want. Thus showing that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R}f_ng \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: By Jensen's inequality and dominated convergence: $|\int_{[n,n+1]}g|\leq \|\mathbf{1}_{[n,n+1]}g\|_{L^q}\to 0$.

Comment: @Snoop I would like to say that I created another post related with your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=\sup|a_n|.$ If $g\in L^q$ then by the Hölder inequality we get $$ \int\limits_\mathbb{R}|f_n||g|\le |a_n|\left (\int\limits_n^{n+1}|g|^q\right )^{1/q}$$ Hence $$M^q\|g\|_q^q\ge M^q\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\limits_n^{n+1} |g|^q\\ \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^q\int\limits_n^{n+1} |g|^q\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left (\int\limits_\mathbb{R}|f_n||g|\right )^q$$ The general term of the last series tends to $0$ which implies $\int f_ng\to 0.$

Comment: Clean, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your reasoning. The first one is that you integrate $g$ when $g$ does not belong to $L^1$ all the time, and this quantity may not exist. It belongs to $L^q$ where $q$ is such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$. In order to avoid this, try using Holder's inequality. Then, you cannot change the test function like that since in order to prove weak convergence, you have to prove that **for any** test function $g$, $\int f_n g \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: That's true and I could simply use Holders inequality at the beginning. In fact, in my last inequality I used Holders. But if I understood you correctly, how would Holders help if I need to fix $g$ and make it as small as I want?

Comment: Because you do not write $\int_n^{n+1} g$ but $\int_n^{n+1} |g|^q$ instead. Then what can you say about $g$ if $\limsup \int_n^{n+1} |g|^q > 0$ ?

Comment: Where does that $|g|^q$ appears from? Because we want to show that $(g,f_n) = \int gf_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. What we could do since $f_n$ is clearly on $L^p$ is use Holders, $\int f_ng \leq \|f_n\|_p\|g\|_q = a_n\|g\|_q.$ But we are back at the same.

Comment: for $g \in L^q$, you have $|\int f_n g |\leq \int |f_n g| = \int_n^{n+1} |f_n g| \leq \left( \int_n^{n+1} |f_n|^p \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_n^{n+1} |g|^q \right)^{1/q} = |a_n| \left( \int_n^{n+1} |g|^q \right)^{1/q} \leq M \left( \int_n^{n+1} g^q \right)^{1/q}$. 

Now, if $\limsup_n  \left( \int_n^{n+1} g^q \right)^{1/q} >0$, you have $g \notin L^q$. Hence, $\limsup_n  \left( \int_n^{n+1} |g|^q \right)^{1/q} =0$ and thus $\int f_n g \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the $\leq M(\dots)$ and the line below that starts with the lim sup. Why would that imply $g \notin L^q$?

Comment: The $\leq M \dots$ is simply a weird formatting of the website. It is part of the big series of inequalities before.

Comment: Furthermore, if the limsup is not $0$ then $\int g^q = + \infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150618/discussion-between-user57-and-beleth).